# Is it good to keep android View references private?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, encapsulation

So, in Java in general, encapsulation is obviously an important consideration, and it is generally standard practice to make every variable private unless there is a  good reason to do otherwise.

However, in most of the Google examples in all of the Android documentation, they never declare their references private.

As in, they write

```
Button someButton;
```

instead of

```
private Button someButton;
```

Currently, what I tend to do is make all view references private, and even then only declare them at the class level if I absolutely need class level access to their data.

Is this the right way to do things, or am I just being paranoid?

Perhaps this convention has something to do with unit testing?

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what you want to do. If you are about to go for inheritance you want to use `protected`. Also when you use a View Binder like [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) you can not use `private` on views because it generates code which sets the field and thus they must be publicly available.

I mean it comes down to what you are using and need to do.

Comment: Since you mention it, what is the point of ButterKnife? I don't see how it saves any code. Maybe I am misunderstanding what it does.

Comment: @Airhead It saves a lot of boilercode. It perfectly shines when you need use method binding like `@OnClick({array_of_view_ids})`. It's personal preference, but I like it even tho it has his flaws. See my questions about Butterknife :)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: Yes**

Encapsulation is very good. You should only expose variables if you really intend them to be visible outside of your class. It makes the classes easier to work with and more readable.

Google often uses ViewHolder Classes with local scope (using no scope declaration) so the members can be accessed by all classes within this scope.

Ideally you start with private member variables and change them to local/protected/public only if you need to provide outside access to them.